# Msg is not defined while sending it in the bookmarks() function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dynamic

How can i send msg to bookmark() as to fetch its value over there.
//adding text to chat window

```
    socket.on("createMessage", (msg,name) => {
      //console.log(msg);
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      let avatar = '<i class="fa fa-user-tie"></i>';
      let bookmark= '<i onclick="bookmark(msg);" class="bookmarks fa fa-bookmark"></i>';
      li.innerHTML = avatar +'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+ '<strong>'+ name + '</strong>'+ bookmark+ '<br>'+ msg;
      all_messages.append(li);
      main__chat__window.scrollTop = main__chat__window.scrollHeight;//scrolled to latest message
    });
const bookmark=(msg)=>{
  console.log(msg);
  req.app.locals.messages_bookmark.push(msg);
  console.log(req.app.locals.messages_bookmark);
}
```

Comment: Its not working while sending only bookmark(msg)

Comment: in `onclick="bookmark(msg);"` msg will not the `msg` from that function - besides ... `bookmark` is a local *variable* not the external function

Comment: Error - msg is not defined

Comment: in onclick="bookmark(msg);" i need the msg from the function  socket.on("createMessage", (msg,name); Is there any way to do it

Comment: Instead of using an inline handler you have to assign the listener in Javascript: `li.querySelector('.bookmarks').addEventListener('click', () => bookmark(msg))` - but this won't work because you shadow the `bookmark` function with another variable with the same name, so rename the local variable instead.